# Unhelpful Jenkins slave error

Tags: svn, jenkins, slave

I have 2 Jenkins slaves that are "identical" and the first one is working fine.  The second one getting this most unhelpful error:

```
At revision 168565
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$BuildRevisionMapTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1299)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$BuildRevisionMapTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1277)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2461)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Has anyone seen this and found a solution?  I occurs after the update from source control, Subversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Jenkins to 1.551 and the plugins to the following seemed to resolve the issue

```
Subversion Plug-in 2.2
This plugin adds the Subversion support (via SVNKit) to Jenkins.


SCM API Plugin 0.2
This plugin provides a new enhanced API for interacting with SCM systems.
```

Answer (score 0):

Smith, this not slave issue it's Subversion client issue which could have been different versions  as Jenkins and slave node or SVN plugin or SVN access from you Jenkins sever issue what you are using..

Try to get compatible versions svn plugin and and make sure your slave has same version of the client or choose from "Manage Jenkins" matching client version.

```
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$BuildRevisionMapTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1299)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$BuildRevisionMapTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1277)
```